# Exception while trying to render "ComponentPresentationList" pushed as a package variable "MainSectionComponents"

Tags: 2011, razormediator

I have pushed a package variable of type "ComponentPresentationList" with name "MainSectionComponents".
I have written razor template code to render the componentpresentation list.

```
   @foreach (var cp in Package.MainSectionComponents) {
     @cp.RenderComponentPresentation()
    }
```

When I try to run it in template builder I get following exception.

DynamicItemFields: Key 'rendercomponentpresentation' Not Found In ItemFields
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.Templating.Rzr881cef20770a4632b97928a77eaf9c6dTemplate.Execute()
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorHandler.CompileAndExecute(DateTime revisionDate, Engine engine, Package package)
   at Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.Razor.RazorMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Compound.CompoundTemplateMediator.Transform(Engine engine, Template templateToTransform, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.ExecuteTemplate(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.InvokeTemplate(Package package, TemplateInvocation templateInvocation, Template template)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Engine.TransformPackage(Template template, Package package)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebuggingEngine.Run()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Debugging.DebugSession.Run()

Can somebody please guide me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 2):

Problem was that the package variable "MainSectionComponents" was pushed in as "ContentType.ComponentArray" instead of "ContentType.ComponentPresentationArray".This was giving following "DynamicItemFields: Key 'rendercomponentpresentation' Not Found In ItemFields" exception.

Comment: In your question you mentioned package variable of type "ComponentPresentationList", which is a separate type other than "ComponentArray" and "ComponentPresentationArray" as you mentioned in your answer. Please try to ask clear questions, it will help you getting good answers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first check if item "MainSectionComponents" exists in the package and is not null.

Also, I am not sure, `ComponentPresentation` class supports method `RenderComponentPresentation()`. So if `@cp.RenderComponentPresentation()` dosn't work, you can try using `TridionHelper.Engine.RenderComponentPresentation(cp.Component, cp.ComponentTemplate);` inside the foreach loop.